# Suggest right approach to develop a CMS application

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system

I am developing a CMS application. Its a very huge deep and with full of configurable features. Current, I am developing it using Asp.net C#, form authentication and by creating UserControls.

There are lot of configurable items need to decide at run time as per user roles and some rules are predefined and some will be defined by Admin at runtime. The all information is stored in DB. I am getting lot of issues with USerControls. I consulted with some other guys who told my approach is wrong, I should go through DB data fetching. I really don't understand what is it? It is something like my all pages will be stores in Database and will construct at runtime and display as per rights?

Could anyone suggest me best approach and if there will be any example please provide?

Any response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should look at using a CMS at this point, given your current experience. Umbraco is built in .NET and is *extremely* customisable. I like to think of it as a development framework more than a CMS, and it might fit your purpose well. Building CMS systems from scratch is tedious and requires a TON of development and testing.

Comment: @Marko - You are right, I have kontakio, Ambrao an dother .Net CMS development but our client needs our own. So, could you suggest some approach?

Comment: @Gaurav, What exactly are the requirements?

Comment: @marko - Requirements are there will be lot of client who have different rights and as per their rights we should display relevant pages and provide them rights to submit comments and their own articles and administrator can provide rights. Its all about the requirements

Comment: Sounds like you're building a blog/forum system. I would still look at a tool like Umbraco with 3rd party package, such as this http://blog4umbraco.codeplex.com/

Comment: @marko - You are very right, this is a good obne. But we need our own coe. I dont know whether we customize Umbraco code and use in our own application?

Comment: That would probably be even harder. Any reason why you need your own code. Frameworks are there to save development time (thus saving money). If you really have to build it from scratch, I would probably suggest looking at ASP.NET MVC. I've only started with it recently but I wish I had known about it earlier. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: Building your own CMS is generally a bad idea when there are already decent open source CMS platforms such as umbraco and DNN available. Ask yourself what benefits you hope to achieve by rolling your own and more importantly, will you have the time to dedicate towards its upkeep once subsequent clients request changes?

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, I can understand the issues for own development. Its requirement of our client. We should have our own code. I have gone through certain CMS available in the market. I saw that all are Database driven Websites. So, I am applying the same approach and sure I will get some fruitful results. Once again, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DataSource binding and etc. to access and read from database? If yes, then you should try avoid it. For example:

1. Build Query like: "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE login = ? and password_hash = ?";
2. Bind parameters 'login' and 'password_hash'
3. Assume that you use "Statement" variable for query:

   ```
   OdbcDataReader result = Statement.ExecuteReader(); //Look for specific database reader for your case    
   while (result.Read()) {
      integer user_id = result.GetInteger(0);
   }
   ```

Something like that.
You can browse more specific database example here:
http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/csharp/ado-net-odbc.html

Comment: thans for your example, its just showing Logins etc. But main query is related to populate pages

Comment: Show me than your query and some logic about how this is working at your side, and I can describe a little further

Comment: Currently we have Stored procedures which are fetching some information and we will display all info in User Controls. Like for User credentials we have spUserCredentials store dprocedure

Answer (score 0):

Look at some CMS systems, such as Kentico, Dotnetnuke or Umbraco. They may support out-of-the-box what you're trying to develop by yourself...